# Android studio fails to download SDK

Tags: android-studio

I just installed android studio 3.0 on my pc. When I opened it up, it asked me to download the sdk first. So it brought up a window and started downloading. But then.. It doesn't download. I have a good internet connection so I dont think that can be the problem. It keeps trying to download a zip file,fails and starts over and this goes on infinitely. So my question is, is there a way to fix this or otherwise manually download the SDK? The website used to have a bundle which contains both but now it only contains the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like download those files manually. When You Start The Download For Additional Setup. There would be a link written in logs. I am attaching an image for it. There would be similar images on your screen when downloading. When you would start download, Then Press Show Details Button You would See It As Shown In Figure.
Copy It And Paste On Browser. Extract Those File On Successful Download And Place Them At Path Specified By You For SDKs

[See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8ikU.png) and [See Here Too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SKfO.png)

[[image]]
[[image]]

Comment: can you please tell me the location where i can get the log files?

Comment: Log Is In The Same Window Where Downloads Are Being Done. Reply me back if it really helps you.

Comment: See The Images Attached In My Post

Comment: So here's the problem. Yes it does print out the files being downloaded but it fails on the first download so I only have the link to the first file. The log is something like this: 
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip
... and keeps printing this out infinitely.

Comment: I think you should download this file and retry for download. If needed Android studio will definitely download next file.

Comment: Or you may reinstall Android Studio.